# WebStorm can't autocompleted styled-component export

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm, intellisense, styled-components

I'm having an issue where a named export for a styled-component const is not being picked up by WebStorm. If I create a function or a react class and export it, WebStorm sees it when starting to type like in my screenshot.

Any ideas why it's not working with styled-components? In my screenshot I cannot see `PageContainer` in the code completion.

Using styled-components v4.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Completion/auto-import for styled components is not currently supported, please follow [WEB-33709](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33709) for updates